# How do you make the Named Ranges box bigger in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, user-interface, named-ranges

The box with the Named ranges in it is too small to see the whole name sometimes, so I have to open the Insert Name dialog.  How do I increase the width of the Named Range box (I don't mind shrinking the formula box)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2003 you can do it with a macro like [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/NameBox.aspx).

Comment: WOW, did that work great.

Comment: @Lance Roberts, Thank you. That's very handy.